# Incorrect parsing to JSON

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have HashMap:

```
public static volatile HashMap<String, GooglePlayGame> games = new HashMap<>();
```

I'm trying to put some objects into this map, then i'm trying to write my HashMap to JSON file.

```
try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {
      GSON.toJson(games, bw);
   } catch (IOException e) {
     log.error("[COULDNT WRITE TO FILE]", e.getMessage());
}
```

Then i'm opening JSON file:

```
{
  "GRID™ Autosport": {
    "Title": "GRID™ Autosport",
    "Last date of update": "11 December, 2019",
    "Current version": "1.6.1RC2-android",
    "Required Android": "no info",
    "Genre": "Racing",
    "Price": "10,00$",
    "IAP": "nothing",
    "Dev email": "googleplay@feralinteractive.com"
  }
}

{
  "FRAMED 2": {
    "Title": "FRAMED 2",
    "Last date of update": "11 July, 2019",
    "Current version": "1.1.1",
    "Required Android": "5.0+",
    "Genre": "Puzzle",
    "Price": "2,00$",
    "IAP": "nothing",
    "Dev email": "support+framed2@noodlecake.com"
  }
}
```

But i got error "JSON standard allows only one top-level value"
How to fix this?

Comment: this is not a correct JSON format. those two objects should be inside a list `[ {}, {} ]` or an object `{ {}, {} }`

Comment: How can i fix it with Gson?
I should put my GameObject to ArrayList or what?

Comment: Since you are using append mode in FileWriter(filename, true) it seems that you are just appending JSONs to the file. Are you creating a new HashMap before calling GSON.toJson()?

Comment: I used Gson, switched to Jackson, and now it works fine. 
I didnt create new map before calling toJson. I just added all new pair "key-value" to this map. After each addition I am recording a new version of the map to the same json.